# Trouble With Minification

Tags: angularjs

Here is a service I have.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
.module('dealerSys')
.factory('permissions',['$rootScope',permService]);  
    function permService($rootScope){
    var permissionList;
    return {
        setPermissions: function (permissions) {

            permissionList = permissions;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('permissionsChanged');
        },
        hasPermission: function (permission) {
            permission = permission.trim();


            permissionList =(permissionList);
            var splitlist = permissionList.trim().split('-');
            var splutPermission = permission.split('-');

            var found = false;
            splutPermission.forEach(function (item) {
                if (splitlist.indexOf(item) > -1) {

                    found = true;

                }
                if (found == true) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return found;

        }
    };

};
```

}())

I have some others like this, and I'm not sure what I'm doing here that isn't safe for minification, but it is throwing an error when minified.

Are there tools out there to help with angular Minification ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[ng-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate) works well in my experience.

```
gulp.task('app', function() {
    gulp.src(".tmp/build.js")
    .pipe(ngannotate())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/scripts"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing that isn't safe is:

```
function permService($rootScope)
```

Minification will rename `$rootscope` to something like `r` and angular doesn't know what `r` is, so it won't be able to do dependency injection.

If you add `permService.$inject = ['$rootScope'];` above your function, this tells angular what you want to inject.